# Нет подключения к базе данных

Tags: база-данных

Выводит такое сообщение. Заранее благодарю
Немає конекту: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

```
<?php 


$sName = "localhost";
$uname = "root";
$pass = "";
$db_name = "test";
try{
    $conn = new PDO ("mysql:host=$sName;db_name=$db_name",$uname,$pass);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    foreach($conn->query("SELECT id FROM user_task") as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    }
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Немає конекту: ". $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `"mysql:host=$sName;db_name=$db_name"` db_name это имя вашей переменной, а сам параметр должен быть без _ => `"mysql:host=$sName;dbname=$db_name"`

Comment: Ех тупик))) Пасіб)